# text selection on a element behind an absolute element

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have an overlay element that hides other div's that contains text. 
the overlay element is absolute positioned.
I want the user to be able to select a text on those div's behind. 
My solution was to hide the overlay (display: none) on user event mouseDown and show it again when the mouseUp event occurred.

that way as soon as the overlay is hidden the user can select the text (as long as the mouseUp hasn't occurred yet).

This solution seems to work on chrome and safari but not on firefox, any advice?

Answer (score 14):

You could use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the element you want to click "through":

```
pointer-events: none;
```

It may need prefix in some browsers.

Examples: Here *without* `pointer-events: none`, you can't select the text:

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  Testing 1 2 3
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Here *with* `pointer-events: none`, you can:

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: yellow;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  Testing 1 2 3
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I probably needed to to add the fact that this overlay (outer) also has a click event that I need (it opens a pop for comments). The idea is this: if the user only clicked without dragging the mouse (while clicking) I consider it as a single click, if a drag was made I consider it as a text selection.

Answer (score 1):

You need help with javascript

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-hodgkin-jqrsp

Disable `pointer-events` when mouse is down.