# React medium editor - need to click twice to be able to write if clicking on placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, medium-editor

I am using [react-medium-editor](https://github.com/wangzuo/react-medium-editor) v. ^1.8.1 in my project. I have the medium editor as an input field in my form:

```
    <MediumEditor
      key={readOnly}
      id="oppgavetekst"
      value={(translation && translation.text[translate]) || ''}
      placeholder="Translate text..."
      disabled={translate === 'from' || readOnly}
      style={{minHeight: 350}}
      onChange={(text) => onChange({name: 'examText', value: text})}
    />
```

And the MediumEditor component looks like this:

```
class MediumEditor extends React.Component {
  static props = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    uniqueID: PropTypes.any,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    style: PropTypes.object,
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProp) {
    if(nextProp.forcedUpdate !== this.props.forcedUpdate)
      return true;

    return false;
  }


  render() {
    const {id, value, onChange, disabled, placeholder, style, uniqueID, forcedUpdate, ...restProps} = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', height: '100%' }} {...restProps}>
        {disabled && <div style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          cursor: 'not-allowed',
          zIndex: 1
        }} />}
        <Editor
          id={id}
          data-testid={`medium-editor-${id}`}
          options={{
            toolbar: {
              buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript']
            },
            spellcheck: false,
            disableEditing: disabled,
            placeholder={text: placeholder || "Exam task..."}
          }}
          onChange={text => onChange(stripHtml(text) === '' ? '' : fixExcelPaste(text))}
          text={value}
          style={{
            ...style,
            background: disabled ? 'transparent' : 'white',
            borderColor: disabled ? 'grey' : '#FF9600',
            overflowY: 'auto',
            color: '#444F55',
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MediumEditor;
```

The problem I have is that if I click on placeholder I need to click one more time to be able to write in that field. If I click anywhere around the placeholder I can start writing immediately, but only where the placeholder is I need to click twice. How can I fix this?

I have tried to create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-shape-deskp?file=/src/index.js) here but for some reason editor styling is not working.

Comment: sorry but in the codesandbox I cannot see any placeholder :/

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz - the css imports are missing, see [Usage](https://github.com/wangzuo/react-medium-editor). Placeholder appears when you add the requires at the top of the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make your placeholder translucent by adding this to your global css file:

```
.medium-editor-placeholder:after {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Clicking on it will select the element behind it.

If you inspect the element in chrome devtools, you can see that the placeholder element overshadows the input element behind it.

[image]

From: [text selection on a element behind an absolute element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674135/text-selection-on-a-element-behind-an-absolute-element)

The `pointer-events: none` apply styling to the placeholder element that make you click it.

Comment: Can be added to global styles.css.